# What is the most optimal code pattern for converting a key value list to associative array in bash?

Tags: arrays, bash, associative-array

Given a key-value list stored in an indexed array, where each key and value are individual elements:

```sh
list=(
'key$1' "value 1 line 1
value 1 line 2
"
'key$2' $'another\nmulti-line\nvalue\n'
)
```

The following code will correctly loop over the key-value pairs and create and associative array:

```sh
declare -A arr
for (( i=0; i<${#list[*]}; i+=2 )); do
    arr+=( ["${list[$i]}"]="${list[$((i+1))]}" );
done
```

```sh
$ declare -p arr
declare -A arr='([key2]="another
multi-line
value
" [key1]="value 1 line 1
value 1 line 2
" )'
$
```

Is there a simpler or more concise way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `arr+=([key]=value)` you could write `arr[key]=value`. Also, `$(())` and the `$`-prefix for variables are not necessary inside `list[…]`.

```
declare -A arr
for (( i=0; i<"${#list[*]}"; i+=2 )); do
    arr["${list[i]}"]="${list[i+1]}"
done
```

Other than that, the script seems fine. I think the only true alternative is to create a command string and `eval`/`declare` that one. The following command assumes that there is at least one key-value pair in `list`:

```
declare -A "arr=($(printf '[%q]=%q ' "${list[@]}"))"
```

This `declare` command should be safe. Also, there shouldn't be any problems with `ARG_MAX` as only built-ins are used. However, the loop seems to be faster by one magnitude, see the following benchmark. Feel free to benchmark both approaches yourself using your actual data (only worth it when dealing with very long arrays).

```
randList() {
    # tr is necessary since the empty string cannot be used as a key
    mapfile -d '' -n "$1" list < <(tr -s \\0 < /dev/urandom)
}
testFor() { declare -A arr; for (( i=0; i<"${#list[*]}"; i+=2 )); do arr["${list[i]}"]="${list[i+1]}"; done; }
testDeclare() { declare -A "arr=($(printf '[%q]=%q ' "${list[@]}"))"; }
prettyTime() { { time "$@"; } 2>&1 | grep -Eom1 '[0-9.sm]+'; }
for size in {1,10,50}000; do
    randList "$size"
    echo "list size = $size"
    printf %s "for loop        "; prettyTime testFor
    printf %s "declare command "; prettyTime testDeclare
done
```

On my laptop (bash 5.0.16, intel i5 M 520) I got these results:

```
list size = 1000
for loop        0m0.059s
declare command 0m0.320s
list size = 10000
for loop        0m0.435s
declare command 0m2.395s
list size = 50000
for loop        0m2.540s
declare command 0m12.276s
```

Comment: I like the one-liner!  I may profile at some point although performance is not critical for my typical use case.

Comment: The one-liner is very cool, I cannot find it documented in Reference Manual.

Comment: @Philippe `declare` and `printf %q` are bash built-ins, therefore they are not documented under `man ...` but under `help ...` or in the [complete bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

Comment: Caching the list size rather than evaluating each loop saves some CPU, and a whle loop saves even more: `testForCache() { declare -i s="${#list[*]}"; declare -A arr; for (( i=0; i<s; i+=2 )); do arr["${list[i]}"]="${list[i+1]}"; done; }` `testWhile() { declare -i i=$((${#list[*]}-1)); declare -A arr; while ((i-=2)); do arr["${list[i]}"]="${list[i+1]}"; done; }`. My timings with list size = 50000: For Loop: 2.523s, Cached length for loop: 2.413, While loop: 2.401s

Comment: @LéaGris Thank you for posting your findings. However, I would say the 0.11 s  and especially the 0.011s between `testFor`, `testForCache`, and `testWhile` and are too short to draw a final conclusion. Test again with bigger arrays to make sure that it wasn't just noise. Also, the `while` loop ignores the last key value pair in `list` and only terminates because of an error. You could structure your loop like this (example with list length 4): `((i=4+1)); while (((i-=2)>0)); do echo "$((i-1))" "$i"; done`.